# How COMMON JS modules are really parsed end executed by Node ? What's the exact algorithm behind the scenes that determines the order and caching?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I'm trying to figure out how COMMON JS modules in Node are really loaded and parsed. What's the algorithm and logic that determines a specific execution order and caching ?

For example, here are these three modules :

Module one :

```
const obj = require("./data_two.js");
require("./data_three.js");
obj.age = 44;
```

Module two :

```
module.exports = {
  name: "Peter",
  surname: "Smith",
};
```

Module three :

```
const obj = require("./data_two.js");
console.log(obj);
```

Now, the module one is executed by Node and the output is the following :

```
{ name: 'Peter', surname: 'Smith' }
```

Why hasn't the property age been added to the output? Could anyone explain this or direct me towards some useful resources so that I can grasp the logic under the hood ?

I've searched the web for a deep explanation but found nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Each module has its own scope. In Module Three in your example, its `const obj` hides the `const obj` in the module which requires it.

The `toobz are full of decent explanations of this module loading process. Here is [just one](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/).

Two things to know.

1. There's a require cache. So each module mentioned in require is loaded exactly once, even if it's mentioned multiple times in require operations in various parts of your code.
2. Each module is wrapped up something like this by the require implementation.

```js
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    const obj = require("./data_two.js");
    console.log(obj);
})
```

So, the scope of that `const obj` is local to the module, not local to the scope holding the require.

If you're used to languages like php where the require operation basically cuts the code from the module and pastes it in place of the require, this can be confusing.

Comment: Do you know some useful resource that I can dive into to grasp this ? I didn't find anything in node official doc.